# Are there any "nidgets" out there still?

Tags: pronunciation, dialects

While researching something unrelated I found this entry on [Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=nidget):

> an idiot sometimes became a nidiot, which, with still-common casual pronunciation, became **nidget, *which, alas, has not survived*.**

(emphasis mine)

Is it true that the "nidget" has not survived?

Friends of mine from Dublin and Liverpool (both sadly long dead, so I cannot ask them) used to use the word, I am quite sure, with regularity  when discussing the deficiencies of neighbours, relatives, and most often, politicians.

[Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=nidget&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1770&year_end=1993&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cnidget%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bnidget%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BNidget%3B%2Cc0) shows little usage of the word in the last 200 years, and most hits on [Google books](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22nidget%22) go back to the 19th century.

Are there some dialects that still make use of this variant of *an idiot*, or have I outlived yet another word?

Comment: Did they really use *nidget*? As in "That nidget"? Or was it merely "He's a nidget," which was probably *an [eejit](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/eejit)*?

Comment: The graphic form may not have survived, but its spirit lives on in "an idjot" with a J

Comment: eejit/idjot is still used in American dialect

Comment: Certainly there are a dozen different ways to contort "an idiot" into something else.  A very common distortion is "idiot" => "idjot", or something thereabouts.  Going from "an idjot" to "a nidget" is then trivial.  Where dialog is written down you will see these distortions spelled several ways, and there is very little significance to the specific spelling, as sometimes the writer will attempt to closely transcribe the speaker's sounds, while other times the writer will choose a familiar spelling.

Comment: Maybe the right question should have been "How many ways can _idiot_ be pronounced in English?"

Comment: ...and a nidget, or nigeot, is no more than an idiot, carelessly spoken; and that is its exact meaning: https://books.google.it/books?id=n9bfivi9ti4C&pg=PA344&dq=nidget+meaning&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiPs4-p9IfRAhVoDcAKHbOsBwcQ6AEIRjAF#v=onepage&q=nidget%20meaning&f=false

Comment: Nidget may not have survived, but [nasshole](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Nass-Hole) is apparently alive and kicking on urbandictionary.com.

Answer (score 2):

According to Google Trends, it is still alive, but dying:

[image]

https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?date=all&q=nidget

Comment: Surely a bloomin' nidget can never die! But those red minidgets I bet are goners for sure.